# JavaScript to detect user activity?

Tags: javascript

[image]

My question is very short. Is it somehow possible to monitor/ detect the user's activity? This does not include any direct mouse input on the website itself. I've never come across something similar and I am pretty sure this exceeds the functionality of any web-based script/application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript you can use `window.onblur` to detect when the tab loses focus (indicating that the user has switched to a different tab or opened a new window). This would probably be enough for preventing cheating on an online exam, though of course there are ways around it.

Without additional software on the user's side, however, I'm not aware of anything that would allow a site to track in detail what users are doing on other opened tabs. That would be a pretty serious security vulnerability.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587634/how-to-determine-whether-the-user-has-switched-to-another-tab-of-the-current-bro)

Comment: hmm, that's interesting. So I guess they might be using that. Or they are too lazy and just try to scare of paranoid students by that warning :D